# Excel VBA Text to Number

Tags: vba, excel, text

I am programming a little and easy add client code. But when I add a client it gives me this little error where I can't get rid off. Maybe it will be an easy solution. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btn_Toevoegen_Click()
   Dim laatsteKlantNummer As Integer

Range("B4:B13").End(xlDown).Select
laatsteKlantNummer = ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = txtKlant
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = txtNaam
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Value = txtAdres
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Value = txtWoonplaats
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 4).Value = txtContact
Me.Hide
Range("B4:B13").Sort Key1:=Range("B4:B13"), Order1:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

This code works properly but the thing happening is when it places it in the excel worksheet it is placed as text and not as number. So it gives me the error: "Number stored as text". After that I can click convert to number. Like this:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxCKF.png)  But is it possible to code it instead of clicking it all the time?

Comment: what line gives the error? This is possible ;)

Comment: If the *txt* values are coming from a form or something similar, force their numerical value with `CLng(txtAdres)` or `CDbl(txtAdres)` or `CDate(txtAdres)`. The one you use will depend upon the type of value you want to put into the cell.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks, that was my problem! Could you place the answer again as answer underneath so I can close it and give you a big upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure on what line you get this error, but for example if its this one:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 4).Value = txtContact
```

You can add this to 'convert' it to a number:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 4).Value = txtContact + 0
```

Comment: Thanks mate, This is also an answer to my question!

Comment: for your problem this is the best answer, and for vba by far the fastest code to run. @Jeepeds answer is also a correct way, but that is advisable if you need to convert it do a date for example, for a normal integer this is the way to go.

Comment: actually what Jeeped commented is way better, depending it it's an integer Clng(txtContact) will Convert-to-Long, and CDbl(Textcontact) would Convert-To-Double (with decimal numbers)....

Comment: All the variables seem to be variants, if he wanted a double he could add like +0,0 and if it has to be a long +0 will make it a long